# Finding consecutive numbers in a sequence without a fixed input using scanner Java

Tags: java

I am very new to this website and writing Java but I am attempting a problem where the user can input any amount of numbers(not separated by spaces or commas) and the output will be the number that appeared the most consecutively and how many times in that chain.

I am running into trouble figuring out how to go about comparing the different chains of numbers that will appear. For instance if there are 3 zeroes in a row followed by 5 sevens i need have those compare with eachother.

I have came up with two variables, one will count the most in a row, and the other will be for second place. Then if second place ever surpasses the most in a row, second place becomes the first and then the value is reset to zero. I could not get that to work and I believe it is because of my use of a for loop.

**Question : I am looking for some guidance of how to properly tackle this problem. Am i going about this all wrong?**

This is the only version of my code that works. If i enter a number like 10000 it will get the 0s correct but a number like 100011 it will get incorrect.

Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sequence
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String numInput;
    int mostInaRow = 1;
    int secondPlace = 1;
    char mostNum = 1;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the numbers");
    numInput = input.next();
    for (int i = 0 ;i < numInput.length() - 1 ; i++  )

    {
      if(numInput.charAt(i) == numInput.charAt(i + 1))
      {
        mostInaRow++;
        secondPlace++;
        mostNum = numInput.charAt(i);
      }
      else
      {

      }
    }
    System.out.println(mostNum);
    System.out.println(mostInaRow);





  }


}
```

Comment: It a good sign you are getting a hang of it, but write down on a piece of paper what exactly is happening for the input you give. That way you will understand what your code is doing & what you need to do. Check your IF-ELSE module once again.

Comment: You are only printing the last result you are getting and not resetting anything when the digit changes.  I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to get a better understanding of what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int i = 0;
    while(i < numInput.length() - 1) {
        int j = i + 1;
        int current = 1;
        while (j < numInput.length() && numInput.charAt(i) == numInput.charAt(j)) {
            current++;
            j++;
        }
        if (current > mostInaRow) {
            mostInaRow = current;
            mostNum = numInput.charAt(i);
        }
        i = j;
    }
```

you can do something like this

Comment: This works! Could you please explain what is going on here? I am getting a bit lost with how you did this.

Comment: the inner loop finds how much consecutive character are equals. When exit from the inner loop, compare if the current consecutive sequence of character is > of the previous max sequence just update mostInaRow and mostNum